# How can i split my raw list of tuples text formatted as each element in next row in sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext

Here what i want

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E43aI.png)

and what i have:

[('Project v1', 'aa125', 'Test', 'Gini', 0.72, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNING', 1, 15, 'run_uuid19', None, 'xgboost_v9', None, None, 'run_uuid19', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v5', 'test-abc', 'Test', 'Gini', 0.93, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNED', 5, 16, 'run_uuid20', None, 'xgboost_v10', None, None, 'run_uuid20', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), 11, 'FINISHED', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v5', 'test-abc2', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.95, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNING', 5, 17, 'run_uuid21', None, 'xgboost_v11', None, None, 'run_uuid21', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), 12, 'IN_PROGRESS', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v5', 'test-abc3', 'Test', 'Gini', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 5, 18, 'run_uuid22', None, 'xgboost_v12', None, None, 'run_uuid22', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), 13, 'IN_PROGRESS', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v5', 'test-challenger', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 5, 20, 'run_uuid24', None, 'xgboost_v19', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, 18), ('Project v3', 'yeni name v3', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.84, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'COMPLETED', 3, 3, 'run_uuid5', None, 'xgboost', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1, 'FINISHED', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v3', 'eabcde3abc', 'Test', 'Calinski-Harabasz', 0.03, 1920791363907, 'some/uri', 'COMPLETED', 3, 10, 'run_uuid13', None, 'kmeans', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v3', 'eabcde', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.87, 1622761363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 3, 6, 'run_uuid8', None, 'xgboost', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 8, 'FAILED', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v3', 'abcd', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.86, 1621761363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNING', 3, 5, 'run_uuid7', None, 'xgboost', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 3, 'FINISHED', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v2', 'exp123', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.87, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 2, 13, 'run_uuid16', None, 'xgboost', 1, 2, 'run_uuid16', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), None, None, 'SME', 'Legal Recovery', 'LIVE', 'Legal Recovery', None), ('Project v1', 'aa124', 'Test', 'Gini', 0.22, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNED', 1, 14, 'run_uuid17', None, 'xgboost_v6', None, None, 'run_uuid17', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v1', 'aa124', 'Test', 'Gini', 0.22, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNED', 1, 14, 'run_uuid18', None, 'tuned_random_forest_21:03:07', None, None, 'run_uuid18', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 11, 50, 50, 862190), None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v3', 'abc', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.85, 1620781363907, 'some/uri', 'TUNED', 3, 4, 'run_uuid6', None, 'xgboost', None, None, 'run_uuid6', 'FAIL', 'token_2', 's3://mlflow/4/run_uuid6/artifacts/audit.csv', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 23, 9, 16, 3, 907000), 'audit notes for model run_uuid6', 'test', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 9, 18, 3, 907000), None, 5, 'IN_PROGRESS', None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v2', 'yeni name v2', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.76, 1620761373907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 2, 2, 'run_uuid4', None, 'logistic_regression', 1, 2, 'run_uuid4', 'PASS', 'token_1', 's3://mlflow/2/run_uuid4/artifacts/audit.csv', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 9, 18, 3, 907000), None, 'test', datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 24, 9, 18, 3, 907000), None, None, None, 'SME', 'Legal Recovery', 'LIVE', 'Legal Recovery', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791373907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid37', None, 'mlp', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid25', None, 'keras', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid26', None, 'light_gbm', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid28', None, 'decision_tree', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid29', None, 'lasso', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid30', None, 'lars', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid31', None, 'ridge', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid32', None, 'kernel_ridge', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid33', None, 'sgd', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid34', None, 'svc', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid35', None, 'k_neighbors_classifier', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620791363907, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid36', None, 'tensorflow', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v1', 'experiment name v1', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.8, 1620721363921, 'some/uri', 'COMPLETED', 1, 1, 'run_uuid1', 'mock_url', 'random_forest', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v1', 'experiment name v1', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.81, 1620721363131, 'some/uri', 'COMPLETED', 1, 1, 'run_uuid2', 'mock_url', 'xgboost', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None), ('Project v4', 'exp cls', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.74, 1620721313930, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 11, 'run_uuid14', None, 'xgboost', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'LIVE', 'Collections', None), ('Project v2', 'exp reg', 'Test', 'MAPE', 0.85, 1620721313930, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 2, 12, 'run_uuid15', None, 'xgboost', 1, 2, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'SME', 'Legal Recovery', 'LIVE', 'Legal Recovery', None), ('Project v4', 'exp cm', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.74, 1620721313930, 'some/uri', 'TRAINED', 4, 19, 'run_uuid23', None, 'xgboost', 3, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Retail', 'Collections', 'CUSTOM', 'Collections', None), ('Project v1', 'experiment name v1', 'Test', 'AUC', 0.82, 1620721313930, 'some/uri', 'COMPLETED', 1, 1, 'run_uuid3', 'mock_url', 'logistic_regression', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'LIVE', None, None)]

i want to start each line with each element if my list has 18 elements it must be 18 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this set of data, formatting the way you want is quite easy.

1. Open **`Find → Replace…`**.
2. In the **`Find`** field, enter `(\('Project)`.
3. In the **`Replace`** field, enter `\n$1`.
4. Make sure the "*Regular Expression*" and "*Wrap*" buttons are selected.
5. Hit the <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button.

and you should be all set. You will have to put the final closing bracket `]` on its own line manually.